# inject js inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

simply i'm trying to implement my own try it yourself page as w3schools which able me to take html and js code and runs it inside iframe

it's my code

```
<html><body>


<script>

    function update()
    {document.getElementById('display').contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = document.getElementById('mycode').value;
    }

</script>

<input onclick="update()" type="button" value="Update page" sandbox>
<textarea id="mycode"></textarea>
<iframe id="display" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"></iframe></body></html>
```

but when i set my code inside the textarea it doesn't run any scripts
i tried sandbox attribute but with no results

Comment: You need to reference the iframe's `contentWindow` property, which is the  `window` of the iframe.  With that, you can manipulate the sandboxed DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to implement a try it your self page.
to do that you may try this.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
   function update{
      '#display'.load(document.getElementById('mycode').value);
   }
</script>
<input onclick="update()" type="button" value="Update page">
<textarea id="mycode"></textarea>
<iframe id="display"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately, not work,
as i remember .load function accepts the path then function to do after loading,
but i need to set the content

Comment: You can check out this tutorial it may help you [link](http://fellowtuts.com/jquery/make-a-html-css-js-try-it-yourself-editor/)

Comment: @HusseinFawzy Plese nform weather you have solved this issue.

Comment: (Y) it works as i need :D plz can you put it as an answer to do it as the solution for any one search for it,

Comment: @ ayush anand the answer is up and i don't know how to inform you

Comment: @HusseinFawzy by ticking a answer you can close the discussion.